# How does hive on spark determine reducer number?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, mapreduce

I enable Hive on Spark according to Cloudera documentation [1](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/admin_hos_oview.html) and [2](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/admin_hos_tuning.html). I now find that reducer number behaves unexpectedly. I wish someone could provide detailed documentation or explanation regarding that.

As far as I know, Hive on MR calculates reducer number based on data volume and `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer`, which means bytes per reducer processes, hence job parallelism can be adjusted automatically. But Hive on Spark seems to treat this parameter differently. Though setting it to very low number (<1K) increases reducer number indeed, no common rule can be applied to different jobs.

Below is segment from Cloudera [tuning documentation for parallelism](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/admin_hos_tuning.html#concept_kzl_dry_y5__section_k53_3tx_1v).

> Adjust hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer to control how much data each reducer processes, and Hive determines an optimal number of partitions, based on the available executors, executor memory settings, the value you set for the property, and other factors. Experiments show that Spark is less sensitive than MapReduce to the value you specify for hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer, as long as enough tasks are generated to keep all available executors busy

Also, I understand that RDD in Spark spills data on disk when memory is not sufficient. If that, the following error messages from Hive on Spark jobs really confuse me.

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 146, fuxi-luoge-105, executor 34): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 34 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 6.2 GB of 6.0 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
```

Comment: You mean that you are using HiveContext on spark? can you attach code sample

Comment: @RefiPeretz I believe the question is about Hive on Spark, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7292

Comment: @iamabug, I am also facing issue, may I know if you were able to figure out a way to fix/find the solution for this problem. I am using CDH 5.16.2 and facing same problem. Any help in this greatly helpful! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Naga Sorry I didn't solve the problem really, I manually set the parameter for different jobs as a workaround. But you can try to find out why spark spill does not work. I will also work on this as soon as I am available.

Comment: @iamabug, Thanks for quick reply , Yes for now am also using  `mapreduce.job.reduces` to set number of reducers manually .. it's really frustrating why it creates for some queries only 1 reducer and others creates required number of reducers.

Comment: @iamabug, I also found this property `hive.spark.use.op.stats` as useful to check and try ( unfortunately I can't test this since I am using CDH 5.16.2) and in that release HIVE-15796 is not included. You can test if you're using latest version of CDH. Here is the [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties) and link for JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15796

Comment: @iamabug, May I know if you've used the parameter I've mentioned or any other parameters to tune your job? If you used other parameters would you mind giving the list of parameters used?

Comment: @Naga Sorry I forgot to mention the parameter name, it's the same as you are using, `mapreduce.job.reduces`.  Besides, we are using CDH 5.15.1, and I could not find another parameter that can help with this situation.

Comment: @iamabug No worries, Thanks for your time :)